# Converting sqlite3 database to PyQt QCompleter/QStringListModel

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

Ok so, I'm setting up a QLineEdit that uses QCompleter with QStringListModel.

I'm trying to setup the QStringListModel to setStringList to a dynamic list that is pulled from my sqlite3 database.

I've tried multiple ways but this seems to be the closest I've got. When I print new_list I can see the list print the database titles but when I try to pass the titles to the setStringList as a variable the program will run but when I search a string there's no auto completion.

Here's the source code that will allow easy testing:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtGui

conn = sqlite3.connect('gamedatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

class window(QMainWindow):

    # Defines Initial Window Settings
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(650, 300, 500, 400) # window geometry
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.move(250, 250)
        self.completer = QCompleter()
        self.edit.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.model = QStringListModel()
        self.completer.setModel(self.model)
        self.get_data()
        self.show()


    def get_data(self):
        c.execute(" SELECT title FROM gamedatabase ")
        results = c.fetchall()
        new_list = [i[0] for i in results]
        print(new_list) # Test print
        self.model.setStringList(new_list) #From here up I was able to get the 
        # code to work but there's no auto completion in the QLineEdit.
def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui = window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I've tried:

```
self.model.setStringList(['this', 'will', 'work',) # This will work.
self.model.setStringList([new_list]) # Does not work, returns error 
# (TypeError: index 0 has type 'list' but 'str' is expected)
```

I've tried googling as much as I could but there doesn't seem to be much information about using PyQt or Sqlite3 in depth. I'm new to python so if there's any forums I've overlooked or missed that provides in depth information into some of these modules please let me know as I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

TLDR: Select all game titles from sqlite3 database and set to setStringList for QCompleter and QStringListModel.

Comment: Your original code works correctly, I do not understand why you want to use the other codes.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully read the question. I'm not trying to use any other code. The code I have above functions and runs but when you type into the QLineEdit bar there's no auto completion happening. I'm wondering if this is due to passing the setStringList as a variable instead of a actual list. I can't figure out how to set the stringlistmodel to pull lists from my database.